# How to fix constructor loop in derived class?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, derived-class

I do not want the derived classes (Ecri1 and Ecri2) to be known elsewhere than CCEAG, but when I try it like this, I get a StackOverflowException, because there will be a loop of constructors beeing called.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CCEAG state = new CCEAG();
        }
    }

    public class CCEAG 
    {
        public CCEAG MachineSpecificState;

        public MachinesEnum CurrentMachine { get; set; }

        public enum MachinesEnum
        {
            ECRI1,
            ECRI2,
        }
        public CCEAG()
        {
            if (MachineSpecificState == null)
            {
                switch (CurrentMachine)
                {
                    case MachinesEnum.ECRI1:
                        MachineSpecificState = new Ecri1();
                        break;
                    case MachinesEnum.ECRI2:
                        MachineSpecificState = new Ecri2();
                        break;
                    default:
                        CurrentMachine = MachinesEnum.ECRI1;
                        MachineSpecificState = new Ecri1();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class Ecri1 : CCEAG
    {
    }

    public class Ecri2 : CCEAG
    {
    }
```

What would be the best practice to solve this problem? Do I need to ditch CCEAG and copy all the code of it to Ecri1 and Ecri2 and make them known to Program?

Comment: Please show all relevant code.  For instance, the code where you're doing the instantiation that is doing this supposed loop behavior.

Comment: Also, please take a look at naming conventions for .net.  Classes should be named with upper camel case, not all caps, and the names should be descriptive enough that you get a sense of what the class is for.

Comment: When the constructor of `CCEAG` is called, `MachineSpecificState` will always be null and `CurrentMachine` will always be `ECRI1`. If they're set at all, it won't be until after the constructor is called.

Comment: @rory.ap This is a minimum example. If you run it, you will see the loop behaviour I described. I have shortended the classnames for this question.

Comment: Make sure `MachineSpecificState` gets a value, it will always be `null` in your example code, hence your problem.

Comment: The way you've written your code right now is that an instance of CCEAG needs an instance of CCEAG. You've basically created a form of infinite loop here. Without knowing *why* you wrote the code like this the only real answer you will get here is you shouldn't write your code like that.

Comment: I can't run it because it fails to compile due to unknown class `ClsMachineStateCCEAG`... https://dotnetfiddle.net/dlxuaj

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, sorry. I edited the code now.

Comment: "What would be the best practice to solve this problem?" *What* problem? It's pretty hard to infer the problem from an incorrect solution. What are you trying to do, exactly? What are all these classes and why are you trying to store a reference to them in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ditch constructing class `CCEAG` from constructor of class `CCEAG`, which leads to infinite recursion you're observing.

If you want to "hide" classes, make them private and create factory public static functions, which create instances of said classes.

```
class CCEAG {
    private class Ecri1 : CCEAG { };
    static public CCEAG createEcri1() { return new Ecri1(); }
};
```

Comment: Upvoted but I believe you have a type-o, and I can't edit myself because it involves less than 6 characters.

Comment: Where? Yea, this limit is annoying.

Comment: The colon and new line after 'public'.  Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're doing.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're assuming static Machine* data (that is shared between CCEAG instances)

```
    public static CCEAG MachineSpecificState;

    public static MachinesEnum CurrentMachine { get; set; }
```

And if possible change these to be `private` instead of `public`